# cannot place methods in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an NSMutableString  named alphabets in my class. I put [alphabets characterAtIndex:i] or [alphabets length] in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:. But when i use reloaddata the app crashes.

Edit: Should I do all the calculations with alphabets outside the tableView and then pass an array of values to tableView.

this is where "alphabets" appears

in @interface

```
NSMutableString *alphabets;
```

@implementation

```
- (IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing: (id)sender {

    Logic *myLogic = [[Logic alloc] init];
    alphabets = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

    alphabets = [myLogic formatSentence: sentenceTextField.text];
    alphabets = [myLogic makeAscending: alphabets];

    [logicTable reloadData];

    // removes keyboard
    [sentenceTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // this causes all the problem  
    cell.textLabel.text = alphabets;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Define 'the app crashes'. Please post the contents of the console explaining the crash.

Comment: You will need to post some code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess without seeing any code, but is "alphabets" already garbage collected by the time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called...? Or do you have a retain hold on it already?

Show us some code snippets. One that creates/instantiates "alphabets" and one where it's used...

EDIT:

Based on the code snippets you've added in your question, it looks to me like you probably need:

```
[alphabets retain];
```

after your last assignment to "alphabets" -- I can't say for sure without seeing the implementation of "[myLogic makeAscending: alphabets]" -- if it calls a method that returns a temporary string, though, you'll need to retain it to keep it in a member variable (ivar).

Of course, since you need to retain it to access it throughout your own object's lifetime, you'll also have to release it appropriately in your implementation of dealloc.

Comment: No garbage collection on iPhone

Comment: Really? What is your source of information about garbage collection on the iPhone...?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I guess I should have said "released / deleted already" instead of "garbage collected" -- in my mind, they are conceptually quite close to each other. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: oh yea thanks you were absolutely right. I was looking all over the place. I thought i needed to understand the iphone framework or something. But no i made a beginners mistake. I guess its not too bad considering i am a beginner. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app is crashing is probably because you are calling reloadData inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath. reloadData will cause cellForRowAtIndexPath to fire again, and you're stuck in an infinite loop until you run out of memory. Try setting a breakpoint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, and watch it happen

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
if (alphabets) {
    cell.textLabel.text = alphabets;
}
```

because from your sample code it seems you might be assigning textLabel.text from an uninitialized pointer until someone edits textField.